Wordpress custom post loop - Cant get post categories
I can't seem to get the categories for a custom post in the loop I have as per the code below: Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong please?
<?php
    $ids = array();
    $pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
    if ($pages) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $ids[] = $page->ID;
        }
    }
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $args = array(
        "paged" => $paged,
        "post__in" => $ids,
        "posts_per_page" => 50000,
        "post_type" => "knowledge_capsules",
        "orderby" => "date",
        "order" => "DESC"
    );
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="kcIndex_feedItemWrapper" id="postID<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
         
    <!-- Need to add in the lightbox content here and fire it open on click -->    
        <a href="#" data-featherlight="#IssueExpandedContent_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_field('knowledgecapsule_teaser_thumbimg'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        
              
            <div class="categoriesHere">
            <?php 
        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_capsules' );
        if(!empty($terms)){
        foreach($terms as $term){
            echo $term->name.'<br>';
        }
        }
        ?>
            </div>
            
         
            
        </a>
    
    <!-- Expanded content -->
    <div id="IssueExpandedContent_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">        
        <?php the_field('knowledgecapsule_teaser_embeddcode'); ?>
        <p class="viewFullVideoLink"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View the full video</a></p>
    </div>
        
    </div>
        
    
    

</div>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <!--<h2>Oh No!!</h2>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>-->
<?php endif; ?>

The Custom post functions code is as below:
<?php

function prefix_create_custom_post_type() {
    /*
     * The $labels describes how the post type appears.
     */
    $labels = array(
        'name'          => 'Knowledge Capsules', // Plural name
        'singular_name' => 'Knowledge Capsule'   // Singular name
    );

    /*
     * The $supports parameter describes what the post type supports
     */
    $supports = array(
        'title',        // Post title
        'editor',       // Post content
        'excerpt',      // Allows short description
        'author',       // Allows showing and choosing author
        'thumbnail',    // Allows feature images
        'comments',     // Enables comments
        'trackbacks',   // Supports trackbacks
        'revisions',    // Shows autosaved version of the posts
        'custom-fields' // Supports by custom fields
    );

    /*
     * The $args parameter holds important parameters for the custom post type
     */
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'description'         => 'Post type post knowledge capsule', // Description
        'supports'            => $supports,
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ), // Allowed taxonomies
        'hierarchical'        => false, // Allows hierarchical categorization, if set to false, the Custom Post Type will behave like Post, else it will behave like Page
        'public'              => true,  // Makes the post type public
        'show_ui'             => true,  // Displays an interface for this post type
        'show_in_menu'        => true,  // Displays in the Admin Menu (the left panel)
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,  // Displays in Appearance -> Menus
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,  // Displays in the black admin bar
        'menu_position'       => 5,     // The position number in the left menu
        'menu_icon'           => '/wp-content/themes/genesis-nal-new/includes/structure/KC_icon.svg',  // The URL for the icon used for this post type
        'can_export'          => true,  // Allows content export using Tools -> Export
        'has_archive'         => true,  // Enables post type archive (by month, date, or year)
        'exclude_from_search' => false, // Excludes posts of this type in the front-end search result page if set to true, include them if set to false
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,  // Allows queries to be performed on the front-end part if set to true
        'capability_type'     => 'post' // Allows read, edit, delete like “Post”
    );

    register_post_type('knowledge_capsules', $args); //Create a post type with the slug is ‘knowledge_capsules’ and arguments in $args.
}
add_action('init', 'prefix_create_custom_post_type');

?>


What is the name of your taxonomy? Is it really knowledge_capsules? Also this "posts_per_page" => 50000, - the 50000 could be replaced with -1 since I'm guessing you don't actually have 50000 posts.

how is the taxonomy named? Is this the code in the functions php that sets it?  $labels = array(
'name'          => 'Knowledge Capsules', // Plural name
'singular_name' => 'Knowledge Capsule'   // Singular name
);

No, how is the taxonomy registered? It seems odd that the taxonomy would have the same registration name as the post type. In your register_taxonomy how is it registered?

Just added the registration code from the functions.php file to the question for reference

Ah, you are using the default WP categories as the taxonomy. In your get_the_terms, change the knowledge_capsules to category. If you look at the docs for get_the_terms, the second argument is for the taxonomy name - which in your case is the default category

Thanks - that's it! Much appreciated.

You got it! I did write an answer as well, since it would probably be helpful to future readers.

The problem is in your get_the_terms(). You are passing the post type name, when it should be the taxonomy registration.
Since you are using the default WP category, you need to update your get_the_terms() to:
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
    
    if(!empty($terms)){
       foreach($terms as $term){
           echo $term->name.'<br>';
       }
    }
?>

